# Objection.js/Knex.js Query Error (error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "null")

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, koa, objection.js

I am attempting to make a patch request to a User model using the Objection.js ORM, and am receiving this error in the server log

" error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "null" "

Here is the simple Patch request:

```
users.patch('/:id', parsers.json, async (ctx, next) => {

  ctx.body = await Users.query()
    .findById(ctx.params.id)
    .patch({ activeP: true })

});
```

and here are links for the underlying user model schema and migration creating the user database.

- https://github.com/WOEIP/truck-tracker/blob/master/backend/models/users.js
- https://github.com/WOEIP/truck-tracker/blob/master/backend/migrations/20181001110232_create-users-table.js

Confused what's happening when I'm not updating any timestamp data with my test, am just updating a boolean value related to User activity. Thank you for the help.